# Java isn't reading a JPG image where as a photo viewer can read it

Tags: java, image, swing

I have a scraped few images from a website. The scraper did not download the image files with the correct extension.

I changed one of the file's extension to `".jpg"` and it opened in Picasa. So I wrote a Java program to change all downloaded image file extensions to `".jpg"`.

Now when I tried to open images in Java, using `Swing`, it's not displaying the image. I am using this code to display. It is working fine with other images downloaded manually from web.

```
String path = "resources\\images\\"+gamePlayer.getName()+".jpg";        
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path));
```

I even tried converting image files to a different format by a third part software(Format Factory) but even it couldn't read the file.
I can open and view all the images in Picasa.

How do I display scraped images with incorrect extensions using `Swing` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is extremely localized, nobody here has the files to inspect with a hex editor to even know if they are actually jpeg or some other image format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picassa is probably inspecting the file signature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) rather than the file extension and therefore opens it correctly. You can't just rename a file and expect your code to understand how to open/display it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. So I guess I should use a different scraper. Should I?

Comment: I would say that you need to make sure that your file is in a proper jpeg format before trying to open it

Comment: When I download it manually. it is in jpeg format. How do I make sure thatit is still in that format when scraper downloads it? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks alot for your prompt response. I think I found a way, by using different url. I am taking down this questiion.